# How to perform a post request with axios on React and pass your data as FormData?

Tags: reactjs, post, request, axios, form-data

There's this  API:http://zssn-backend-example.herokuapp.com/api/, detailed here: http://zssn-backend-example.herokuapp.com/swagger-api/index.html#!/people/Api_People_index . I am trying to do a POST request on this endpoint "/people/{person_id}/properties/trade_item.json"(Make a trade transaction between survivors). On the  Website for testing I filled the fields with the following data and got 204 response:

person_id:34e183a6-965e-4a61-8db5-5df9103f4d4b

consumer[name]: Person4

consumer[pick]:  AK47:1;Campbell Soup:1

consumer[payment]: First Aid Pouch:2

I investigated a Little and got
[this information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLPSJ.png)

didn't understand the "PROPERTY[KEY]:VALUE" representation

When I try to the  Request with this code, with the same values(by the way, the database of this API is cleared each 24 hours, so those value might not work, even if you do it in the right way):

this is My code:

```
    async function handleTrade(e){

   e.preventDefault();

     const config = {
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       },
     };
     await api.post(
       "/people/" + match.params.id + "/properties/trade_item.json",
       {
         person_id:match.params.id,
         name: survivorRef.current,
         pick: survivorItemsToPick,
         payment: userItemsToPay,
       },
       config
     );
```

And this is what I get:
Request:
[request-description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT3Nw.png)

Response:
[response-description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l57pq.png)

How Can i make this request in the right way in order to get the same result as the first Image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FormData to send the request, I made an example:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("customer[name]", "Person4");   
data.append("customer[pick]", "AK47:1");         
await api.post("/people/" + match.params.id + "/properties/trade_item.json", data, config)
```